# Get localhost to load website in directory not in /var/www/html

Tags: apache2.4, php-8.2

I am not an experienced `Apache` coder/developer. I've edited `.conf` files before, but it's been a minute or several.

I have `Apache/2.4.52` on my `Ubuntu 22.04` machine.  For what it's worth, I use `PHP8.1.2`

How can I view my development websites (dev-sites) via localhost when the directory I have my websites in is not `/var/www/html`?

I build my sites(code) in `/home/jdc44/Websites/` I.e: one such site is: `/home/jdc44/Websites/LivingMuayThai` There is a live website, but I want to make changes to the site/code and be able to view it locally before pushing any issues live. I would like to view the site at: `localhost/livingmuaythai` or camel-cased: `localhost/LivingMuayThai` as that is the name of the directory the code is in.

I'll post my code here and hope someone can tell me what I'm missing or how to do it if this is all wrong. I followed this tutorial from 2009, but it is not working. Maybe things have changed...

[How to configure apache webserver on linux](https://tuxtweaks.com/2009/07/how-to-configure-apache-linux/)

I created a `livingmuaythai.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

```
## /etc/apache2/sites-available/livingmuaythai.conf
## I removed all the commented lines for space

<VirtualHost *:80>
    
  # ServerName www.example.com
  ServerName livingmuaythai  // do I need a .com on this?

  ServerAdmin johncowan54@gmail.com
  DocumentRoot /home/jdc44/Websites/LivingMuayThai/

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  <Directory /home/jdc44/Websites/LivingMuayThai/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  <FilesMatch "\.*">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  </FilesMatch>
  
</VirtualHost>
```

```
## /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost livingmuaythai
```

I enabled the site:

```
sudo a2ensite livingmuaythai
```

A symlink was created in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. The setup created this, not me.

```
livingmuaythai.conf -> ../sites-available/livingmuaythai.conf
```

Then restarted/reloaded `Apache`

When I go to `http://localhost/livingmuaythai/index.html` I get a `404 Not Found` page.

Note: I have a firewall and port 80 is open.

Thoughts?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks like your paths are wrong. Try `http://localhost/index.html`

Comment: @MisterSmith thanks, but that just takes me to the Apache2 Default Page, which I believe is in `/var/www/html`

Answer (score 0):

You have talked about *enabling your new site*, but not about *disabling the default site*, so my guess is you have both still set up. You can check this in two ways:

- Look at the content of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` - as you've seen, this is the folder managed by the `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` commands, as a convenient way of turning sites on and off
- Run `sudo apache2ctl -S`, which gives a breakdown of *all* the "virtual hosts" Apache thinks are configured, and where they're defined

Probably, you just want to run `sudo a2dissite some-default-site-in-the-list`

---

At this point, it's worth a quick detour to understand how Apache resolves sites:

1. All configuration files are processed and combined, as though they were all in one file. All the `Include` lines and symlinks are just for human convenience.
2. Apache receives a request from the browser, on a particular *destination IP address* and *port*, with a particular HTTP *Host* header or TLS SNI hostname. For instance, a request to the URL `http://example.com/foo/bar/baz` will have IP address `93.184.216.34` (that's what I currently get when I run `nslookup example.com`), port `80` and Host header `example.com`
3. The IP address and port are matched against the `<VirtualHost>` blocks in the configuration.
4. If no blocks mention the specific IP address and port, `<VirtualHost>` blocks specifying an IP address and/or port of `*` are matched.
5. The matching blocks are examined in order, looking at the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` lines they contain. The first time one is found that matches the requested hostname, that VirtualHost block is used.
6. If none of the blocks has a matching `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`, the first block is used (out of the list matching IP address and port).

In your case, `<VirtualHost *:80>` means "any IP address, port 80", and `ServerName livingmuaythai` says this should be a good choice for URLs like `http://livingmuaythai/foo/bar`.

Your request `http://localhost/livingmuaythai/index.html` will look for, in order:

1. `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` with `ServerName localhost` or `ServerAlias localhost`
2. The first `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` block defined
3. `<VirtualHost *:80>` with `ServerName localhost` or `ServerAlias localhost`
4. The first `<VirtualHost *:80>` block defined

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation. Much appreciated.  I removed the symlink to the default config, but when I run `localhost` in my browser, I still see the `Apache` welcome page.  `localhost/livingmuaythai/` now shows a `403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.` page.  I'm thinking it is a permissions thing?